# Efficient way of filtering by datetime in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, pandas-groupby

Given the `DataFrame` generated by:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

np.random.seed(0)
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=14, freq='9H')
ids = [1]*5 + [2]*2 + [3]*7
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ids, 'time_entered': rng, 'val': np.random.randn(len(rng))})
```

`df`:

```
    id  time_entered        val
0   1   2015-02-24 00:00:00 1.764052
1   1   2015-02-24 09:00:00 0.400157
2   1   2015-02-24 18:00:00 0.978738
3   1   2015-02-25 03:00:00 2.240893
4   1   2015-02-25 12:00:00 1.867558
5   2   2015-02-25 21:00:00 -0.977278
6   2   2015-02-26 06:00:00 0.950088
7   3   2015-02-26 15:00:00 -0.151357
8   3   2015-02-27 00:00:00 -0.103219
9   3   2015-02-27 09:00:00 0.410599
10  3   2015-02-27 18:00:00 0.144044
11  3   2015-02-28 03:00:00 1.454274
12  3   2015-02-28 12:00:00 0.761038
13  3   2015-02-28 21:00:00 0.121675
```

I need to, for each `id`, remove rows which are more than 24hours (1 day) from the latest `time_entered`, for that `id`. My current solution:

```
def custom_transform(x):
    datetime_from = x["time_entered"].max() - timedelta(days=1)
    x = x[x["time_entered"] > datetime_from]
    return x

df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: custom_transform(x)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

which gives the correct, expected, output:

```
    id  time_entered        val
0   1   2015-02-24 18:00:00 0.978738
1   1   2015-02-25 03:00:00 2.240893
2   1   2015-02-25 12:00:00 1.867558
3   2   2015-02-25 21:00:00 -0.977278
4   2   2015-02-26 06:00:00 0.950088
5   3   2015-02-28 03:00:00 1.454274
6   3   2015-02-28 12:00:00 0.761038
7   3   2015-02-28 21:00:00 0.121675
```

However, my real data is tens of millions of rows, and hundreds of thousands of unique ids, because of this, this solution is infeasible (takes very long time).

Is there a more efficient way to filter the data? I appreciate all ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, avoid `groupby().apply()` since it's not vectorized across groups, not to mention the overhead for memory allocation if you are returning new dataframes as in your case.

How about finding the time threshold with `groupby().transform` then use boolean indexing on the whole data:

```
time_max_by_id = df.groupby('id')['time_entered'].transform('max') - pd.Timedelta('1D')
df[df['time_entered'] > time_max_by_id]
```

Output:

```
    id        time_entered       val
2    1 2015-02-24 18:00:00  0.978738
3    1 2015-02-25 03:00:00  2.240893
4    1 2015-02-25 12:00:00  1.867558
5    2 2015-02-25 21:00:00 -0.977278
6    2 2015-02-26 06:00:00  0.950088
11   3 2015-02-28 03:00:00  1.454274
12   3 2015-02-28 12:00:00  0.761038
13   3 2015-02-28 21:00:00  0.121675
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x : x[(x['time_entered'].max()-x['time_entered'])<pd.Timedelta('1D')]).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[322]: 
   id        time_entered       val
0   1 2015-02-24 18:00:00  0.978738
1   1 2015-02-25 03:00:00  2.240893
2   1 2015-02-25 12:00:00  1.867558
3   2 2015-02-25 21:00:00 -0.977278
4   2 2015-02-26 06:00:00  0.950088
5   3 2015-02-28 03:00:00  1.454274
6   3 2015-02-28 12:00:00  0.761038
7   3 2015-02-28 21:00:00  0.121675
```